# How to deal with "Illegal macro definition in command line or defines page" error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm trying to embed a certain text file as a resource in my EXE, and I'm having a heck of a time of it.

I made a simple one-line `.rc` file and added it to the project, but BRCC32 chokes on it with a completely unhelpful error:

> [BRCC32 Error] MyRes.rc(1): Fatal error Illegal macro definition in command line or defines page.

Here's the contents of the file, in its entirety:

```
DATA_BASIC_ORDER     RCDATA Data\Data_BasicOrder.txt
```

This only happens if I build in the IDE.  I'm able to successfully build a .RES file from this on the command line, and opening it in a hex editor shows both the resource name and the contents of the text file, but if I link it in with a `{$R}` directive, the resource doesn't show up in the EXE. I verified it with ResHacker; the resource just isn't there.  So something very strange is going on.

I have tried shutting down and restarting the IDE.  No change.  I also opened the `.rc` file in a hex editor to make sure that there are no weird characters messing things up, but no, it's a plain ANSI text file.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on with this and how I can fix it?

**EDIT:** It keeps getting weirder.  If I leave the file line completely blank, I still get the same error.  But if I remove the file from the project, (removing it from the listing in the Project Explorer,) that error message goes away, but it's still not showing up in the build.

Comment: How can we reproduce this? Without a reproduction, it's going to be tricky.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah, unfortunately this is a project from work, so sharing a repro case is also tricky, to say the least.  I was hoping someone on here had seen this error message before and knew how to handle it.  After Googling it, I see a few people asking about this error and no one getting any useful answers, so I'm kind of at the end of my rope here.  I'm like, "help me, Obi-Wan Stackovi, you're my only hope!"

Comment: I never worked much with RC file or read that much about them. The only thing I noticed is that they tend to give that kind of error when using file formats other than ANSI.

Comment: @KenBourassa: thanks for the note.  That's one thing I already checked, unfortunately, opening it in a hex editor to make sure it's ANSI.

Comment: Step 1 is to isolate the problem. That's where I'd start.

Comment: I can confirm this issue. The .res file is never created. If you leave the line with both the .res and rc files specified, the resource is not linked in even if you compile it from the command line first. If you compile from the command line, and then use `{$R MyResource.res}` and build, the resource is correctly added.

Comment: @Ken Could you edit the repro into the question. I wasn't able to reproduce. I guess I took a different path at some point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Unfortunately, no. I'd closed XE; when I reopened it to grab the code that repro'd it and compiled, it no longer generates the error. (The behavior is the same as I described, but the message no longer appears. The resource is sometimes included in the executable and sometimes not.)

Comment: As you just said on Google+, *remember, if the other guy can't reproduce the bug, it may as well not exist.*

Comment: I found a reproduction: create a project, add a .rc file, add anything e.g. "Something 23 Project1_Icon.ico" (but make sure the file exists), then in the compiler settings, add one or more conditional defines, presumably long ones with one or more underscores

Answer (score 1):

Backslash look suspicious. Try to quote it:

```
RCDATA Data\\Data_BasicOrder.txt
```

Comment: Nope, same error.  And like I said, this does compile correctly from the command line compiler.  (But then the resource doesn't link in, so... yeah.)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message denotes, the answer to your problem may be visible in the command line for the call to the BRCC32.exe tool made by the compiler.

I ran into this error by trying to add a number of extra 'Conditional defines' in the compiler configuration. I suspect there's a limit to the number and the length (and/or the number of underscores) allowed for conditional defines that are passed to brcc32 as well (using the `-d` parameter, apparently)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and it kept pointing to *MyResource.rc* even though the problem was in one of the Conditional Defines. Somehow two different defines ended up on the same line separated by a comma. `PHNOCODE,DECODE`
After correcting the Defines my project builds properly.